# java jaxb: converting xml to a java list of enums

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm working on a project in java where xml input is read via xjc into generated classes. So the xsd schema is converted into java type.

All is well, and usually I have no problems, but I can't seem to get this conversion right: I want to convert an xml list of enums into a java list of enums.

This is my xsd part:

```
   <xs:attribute name="myTypes" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType >
            <xs:list itemType="output.myType"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>

    <xs:simpleType name="output.myType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:javaType
                    name="packagename.MyEnumType"
                    parseMethod="...TypeConverter.unmarshalOutputMyType"
                    printMethod="...TypeConverter.marshalOutputMyType"
                />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="option1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="option2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="option3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

When doing the xjc generation I keep getting this in the generated java class:

```
public List<String> getMyTypes()
```

While I'm expecting this:

```
public List<MyEnumType> getMyTypes()
```

How can I make jaxb/xjc to use the List for the generated list, in stead of just parsing the type into a List of Strings? The conversion works perfect if I'm just using the output.myType directly as simpleType for the attribute, but it doesn't work when I try to make the attribute into a list of those items.